# Django and Celery - key error at checking if GroupResult ready

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I want to check if my task group is ready. If I do it inside celery task, it works fine:

```
from time import sleep

from celery import task, group
from celery.result import GroupResult

@task
def a():
    sleep(10)


@task
def b():
    c = group(a.si())()
    c.save()
    saved_result = GroupResult.restore(c.id)
    print saved_result.ready()


b.apply_async()
```

However, it doesn't work inside my Django view.

```
task_result = GroupResult.restore(my_hash)
print type(task_result)
if task_result.ready(): # this throws an error
     print 'ready!'
```

Error:

```
    if task_result.ready():
  File "/home/kam/project1_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 259, in ready
    return self.state in self.backend.READY_STATES
  File "/home/kam/project1_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 396, in state
    return self._get_task_meta()['status']
  File "/home/kam/project1_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 341, in _get_task_meta
    return self._maybe_set_cache(self.backend.get_task_meta(self.id))
  File "/home/kam/project1_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 332, in _maybe_set_cache
    state = meta['status']
KeyError: 'status'
```

Also when I call it inside celery beat task it raises an error.

I'm using Redis as backend. My celery settings:

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I had a group with no tasks inside.